# getting all the Active Record models in app/models directory

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, metaprogramming

I'm planning to create a ruby gem which requires to get all the ActiveRecord models from the directory (typically)

RAILS_ROOT/app/models

how can I get the list of model names (physical) in ruby (ruby 1.9)

cheers

sameera

Answer (score 1):

So, if the class name matches with the file name, you can use something like this:

```
# models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
end

Dir.glob("./models/*.rb").each {|model| require model}
user = User.new
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ActiveRecord::Base.subclasses.collect(&:name)
```

Returns all the model name.